# Git "missing" commit

Tags: git

I'm in a situation where some changes made in a feature branch are not reflected in master, even though this branch was merged into it.  I'm at a loss to understand why.  For simplicity, let's say this commit has a hash "A" and changed file "file"

This can probably best be illustrated by the following commands:

```
$ git checkout master

$ git branch --contains A
* master
feature_branch

$ git log file | grep A
(no output)

$ git checkout feature_branch

$ git log file | grep A
A
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?  More importantly, is there anything that can be done to prevent this in the future?

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by a few people, the following does show the commit:

```
$ git checkout master

$ git log --follow file | grep A
A
```

But the thing is... the file was **not** renamed.  So that doesn't fully explain things, either..

Comment: What output, if any, do you get if you run `git log A..master`?

Comment: How did you merge? Merging can rewrite commits (e.g. squash).

Comment: There is output.  A lot of output.
This particular commit was made more than a month ago.. it was only recently brought to my attention that it didn't get reflected in master.

Comment: Can you provide steps for reproducing this condition? Lots of ways to get here, can't tell which one you came by without a lot more info... but a reproducer would be perfect.

Comment: Some of those involve people being sloppy around merges, and/or resolving conflicts without looking at exactly what they are. Others involve explicit revert commits.

Comment: @EricPlaton 
I believe in this case all of the merges were done as pull requests in Atlassian Stash, so I'm not really sure how that maps to specific git commands.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Don't know how to reproduce it.  If I could, I'd know what *not* to do :)

If it were a case of a merge conflict that was improperly resolved.. I'd still expect to see that hash in the history of that file, though?

Comment: Not if it was "resolved" by not applying the relevant changeset portion at all.

Comment: Is file present in the file system with `master` checked out?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So if you did something like git merge -s ours (for the record - fairly certain this was not done) it'd wipe out one version of the file from the history?

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, it is.  But the contents don't reflect the changes made.

Comment: If the file were _coming from_ the merge, it wouldn't show up after that. If it existed _before_ the merge, you've got something more interesting, but I'm not sure guessing will be particularly productive.

Comment: Have you tried to merge the feature branch to master again, see what happens? It should come clean, but if it doesn't then you'd be a step closer. What could have happened is that there was a conflict while merging the feature branch the first time, and the developer doing the manual conflict resolution discarded the changes. Go check the merge commit in that case.

Comment: @Gauthier When I try to merge feature_branch into master, it says "Already up-to-date."

Comment: When you checkout to the point when feature_branch was merged into master, what is the output of `git diff feature_branch -- file`  ?

Answer (score 8):

**You are a victim of an evil merge.**

Here is how to reproduce it

```
git init testrepo
cd testrepo

touch initial
git add initial
git commit -m 'initial commit'

git checkout -b feature_branch
echo "A" >> file
git add file
git commit -m 'file committed'

git checkout master
```

Now do an interactive merge as if there were merge conflicts

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff feature_branch
```

and move the file `file` (evil merge).

```
testrepo (master|MERGING)

git mv file someOtherFile
git commit
```

Now you will see that branch master contains the commit (in my case `9469682`) that introduced file `file`

```
 git branch --contains 9469682
  feature_branch
 * master
```

But a git log will not show it, because it was moved

```
 git log -- file
 (no output)
```

Use

```
git log --follow -- file
```

and the commit appears again.

Also keep in mind that the merge can get more evil. If the `file`'s content also changed a lot than èven `git log --follow` will not detect it, because of the rename threshold.

In this case use [`git log --follow --find-renames=`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to adjust the rename threshold.

> If generating diffs, detect and report renames for each commit. For following files across renames while traversing history, see --follow. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, -M90% means Git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and is thus the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is the same as -M5%. To limit detection to exact renames, use -M100%. The default similarity index is 50%.

Comment: The thing is, these files were not renamed.
I just became aware of *another* commit from another feature branch that exhibited the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow the location of the file has changed, you might need to tell `git log` to `follow`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log --follow -- file | grep A
```

You can check if there is a difference between `git log --oneline -- file` and `git log --oneline --follow -- file`, to see if the file has been relocated.

Comment: I don't believe the location of the file has changed.
But I ran the command anyway, just to see what'd happen..
and surprisingly (shockingly) lo and behold, there is the missing commit..

Comment: @Gauthier - think there's a typo there: `--online` --> `--oneline` ?