# Latest change in a file is not synced when git repo is pulled

Tags: git, tfs

I have a very weird behavior in a git repository I'm working with, and have no idea of how to solve it.

On a code file (SummitParagraphPresenter.cs), on the 6 of March, some changes were done. I can see them in the history of the folder, and the diff is correct:
[image: Folder history]

But if I look at the history for that specific file, I cannot see that commit.
Also if I pull from the repository, I get the code as it was before that commit.

Another weird thing is that the VisualStudio TFS web code browser shows the file with the full history and with the changes that have been made on that commit.

How can I solve the problem of getting the actual latest version of the file? And what could have caused it to go wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you run git from the command line? Try `git log -- <path/to/your/file>`, and compare with `git log --follow -- <path/to/your/file>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990752/git-missing-commit?noredirect=1#comment46231919_28990752

Comment: They are different indeed: just `log` shows just the commit that shows in the file history. `log --follow` shows also the other commit that I'm "missing"

Comment: But if I understand correctly, the follow shows also when a file is moved. But in this case, the file was never moved, it's still in the same folder, with the same filename

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the commit does not show in the history of the file is probably because your tool does not call `git log` with `--follow`. Look if you can set it up to use `--follow`.

I can speculate on why the changes of the "hidden" commit do not show in the working file:

- you don't have the latest commit checked out
- the changes introduced in the hidden commit were reverted in another commit. This might happen without you noticing, for example while resolving conflicts manually. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990752/git-missing-commit?noredirect=1#comment46231919_28990752). It would be interesting to see the result of `git log --graph --oneline --follow -- <path/to/your/file>`.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that this was case (change reverted by another commit), but I would have expected to see in the history who did the merge that screwed up everything :)
The cmd line command you ask gives the same as the follow, just with a nicer formatting and many colored bars :)

Comment: I hoped you would see the merge commit in the history, and see what happened there. Hopefully you'd see the revert, and maybe get the name of the developer to blame :) (it often turns out to be oneself).

Comment: Stepping through the history I found out that a later merge reverted some changes. But now have to revert that commit. It's weird that that merge is not showing in the history